# Base 64 encoding / decoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

I'm having issues decoding a Base64 string. Here's the pertaining code (within a category file):

```
- (NSString *)base64DecodedString {
    NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:self options:0];
    NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Encoded String: %@\n"
           "Decoded String: %@\n"
           "Reencoded Check: %@\n", self, decodedString, [decodedString base64EncodedString]);

    return decodedString;
}

- (NSString*)base64EncodedString {
    NSData *encodedData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *encodedString = [encodedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    return encodedString;
}
```

Using `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, when calling the `base64DecodedString` category method, I get the following output:

```
Encoded String: XMEBbbUGO4wuZ8Eljx6x8Q==
Decoded String: \Ámµ;.gÁ%±ñ
Reencoded Check: (null)

Encoded String: NBbA3SzI5j8ioOTeQC5WxNvEFNg0WFy4nRjmCSdypCI=
Decoded String: 4ÀÝ,Èæ?" äÞ@.VÄÛÄØ4X\¸æ 'r¤"
Reencoded Check: (null)
```

Using the same code above, but with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` I get the following output:

```
Encoded String: oP6u7jErDp4KHzC6WmzHEw==
Decoded String: (null)
Reencoded Check: (null)

Encoded String: qjne07HA4PFIFrwTP9E/ejK6XtWoFtbgdDTpL8wmfgY=
Decoded String: (null)
Reencoded Check: (null)
```

Any ideas as to what is going on? In either case, the decoded string is incorrect and the reencoding check does not produce the original string.

Comment: What are you *expecting* the "decoded string" to be? The data in the encoded strings doesn't appear to be text; it can't be represented as an ASCII (or UTF8) string.

Comment: @duskwuff I'm using this as the key for decrypting another file. I'm not sure what the key is *supposed* to be, but using the result of the above as the key does not yield a valid file. I have decrypted another file successfully using a known key with the same function so I'm assuming the way the key is being generated is incorrect. The other possibility is that the way the file is being encrypted has changed.

Comment: @duskwuff, in any case, given the Base64 encoded input, I'm wondering how you would decode it correctly?

Comment: Did u try some other options:
Data =[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:str options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
str = [Data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

Comment: @Mike.R I tried that (https://gist.github.com/nmock/37d500749a11eb1c2fa1), but am still having issues using it as the key. Any way to make it so that the reencoding produces the original result?

Comment: nmock did my answer helped you?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to try to use more `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. For Instance:

```
- (NSString *)base64DecodedString {
NSString *tempString = @"Here you come";
NSData *data = [tempString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *decodedData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Simple String: %@\n"
      "Decoded String: %@\n"
      , tempString, decodedData);
return nil;
```

}

In your case `[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:self options:0];` return nil.(when I tried it).
Simple example:
[iOS 7: Base64 Encode and Decode NSData and NSString Objects](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/encode-decode-using-base64.html)

Hope I helped.